# List all open sockets in /dev/tcp/localhost/

Tags: linux, port, tcp, localhost, sockets

Is it possible to list all open sockets in `/dev/tcp/localhost/` on a Linux machine?

I want to list all sockets where the following command would return `0`:

```
timeout 2 bash -c "cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/localhost/8014"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list all TCP sockets accepting connections you could simply use `netstat -nlt`.